# jQuery-File-Upload - Output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload

I use the jQuery-File-Upload. The form data is written to the database as I want to.
But when I upload an image I receive the following message:

```
{"files":[{"name":"1430606695-9544","size":0,"type":"","error":"No file was uploaded"}]}
```

Why does it say "No file was uploaded" etc.?

**index.php:**

```
<?php
/*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin PHP Example 5.14
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */

$options = array(
    'delete_type' => 'POST',
    'db_host' => 'localhost',
    'db_user' => 'helloworld',
    'db_pass' => 'helloworld',
    'db_name' => 'helloworld',
    'db_table' => 'files'
);

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');

class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler {

    protected function initialize() {
        $this->db = new mysqli(
            $this->options['db_host'],
            $this->options['db_user'],
            $this->options['db_pass'],
            $this->options['db_name']
        );
        parent::initialize();
        $this->db->close();
    }

    protected function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
        $file->title = @$_REQUEST['title'][$index];
        $file->description = @$_REQUEST['description'][$index];
    }

    protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
            $index = null, $content_range = null) {
        $file = parent::handle_file_upload(
            $uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range
        );
        if (empty($file->error)) {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
                .'` (`name`, `size`, `type`, `title`, `description`)'
                .' VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param(
                'sisss',
                $file->name,
                $file->size,
                $file->type,
                $file->title,
                $file->description
            );
            $query->execute();
            $file->id = $this->db->insert_id;
        }
        return $file;
    }

    protected function set_additional_file_properties($file) {
        parent::set_additional_file_properties($file);
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
            $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `type`, `title`, `description` FROM `'
                .$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `name`=?';
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param('s', $file->name);
            $query->execute();
            $query->bind_result(
                $id,
                $type,
                $title,
                $description
            );
            while ($query->fetch()) {
                $file->id = $id;
                $file->type = $type;
                $file->title = $title;
                $file->description = $description;
            }
        }
    }

    public function delete($print_response = true) {
        $response = parent::delete(false);
        foreach ($response as $name => $deleted) {
            if ($deleted) {
                $sql = 'DELETE FROM `'
                    .$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `name`=?';
                $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $query->bind_param('s', $name);
                $query->execute();
            }
        } 
        return $this->generate_response($response, $print_response);
    }    
}

$upload_handler = new CustomUploadHandler($options);
```

**basic-plus.html**

```
        <form id="fileupload" action="server/php/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        <span>Add files...</span>
        <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
        <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- The global progress bar -->
    <div id="progress" class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- The container for the uploaded files -->
    <div id="files" class="files"></div>

        <label class="title">
    <span>Title:</span><br>
    <input name="title[]" class="form-control" value="testtitel">
</label>
<label class="description">
    <span>Description:</span><br>
    <input name="description[]" class="form-control" value="testdescription">
</label>

</form>

    <script>
/*jslint unparam: true, regexp: true */
/*global window, $ */
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io' ?
                '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'server/php/',
        uploadButton = $('<button/>')
            .addClass('btn btn-primary')
            .prop('disabled', true)
            .text('Processing...')
            .on('click', function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data();
                $this
                    .off('click')
                    .text('Abort')
                    .on('click', function () {
                        $this.remove();
                        data.abort();
                    });
                data.submit().always(function () {
                    $this.remove();
                });
            });
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: false,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
        // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
        // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
        // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
        previewMaxWidth: 100,
        previewMaxHeight: 100,
        previewCrop: true
    }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            var node = $('<p/>')
                    .append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
            if (!index) {
                node
                    .append('<br>')
                    .append(uploadButton.clone(true).data(data));
            }
            node.appendTo(data.context);
        });
    }).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
        var index = data.index,
            file = data.files[index],
            node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
        if (file.preview) {
            node
                .prepend('<br>')
                .prepend(file.preview);
        }
        if (file.error) {
            node
                .append('<br>')
                .append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error));
        }
        if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
            data.context.find('button')
                .text('Upload')
                .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
        }
    }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            if (file.url) {
                var link = $('<a>')
                    .attr('target', '_blank')
                    .prop('href', file.url);
                $(data.context.children()[index])
                    .wrap(link);
            } else if (file.error) {
                var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error);
                $(data.context.children()[index])
                    .append('<br>')
                    .append(error);
            }
        });
    }).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index) {
            var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text('File upload failed.');
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .append('<br>')
                .append(error);
        });
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
</script>
```

main.js

```
    /*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin JS Example 8.9.1
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */

/* global $, window */

$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:

    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'server/php/'
}).on('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    data.formData = data.context.find(':input').serializeArray();
});

    // Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        'redirect',
        window.location.href.replace(
            /\/[^\/]*$/,
            '/cors/result.html?%s'
        )
    );

    if (window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io') {
        // Demo settings:
        $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
            url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
            // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
            // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
            // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
            disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
            maxFileSize: 5000000,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
        });
        // Upload server status check for browsers with CORS support:
        if ($.support.cors) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
                type: 'HEAD'
            }).fail(function () {
                $('<div class="alert alert-danger"/>')
                    .text('Upload server currently unavailable - ' +
                            new Date())
                    .appendTo('#fileupload');
            });
        }
    } else {
        // Load existing files:
        $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
        $.ajax({
            // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
            //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
            url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
            dataType: 'json',
            context: $('#fileupload')[0]
        }).always(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Answer (score 1):

what does your network stack say?

ie:  go to the "developer" view in chrome, (view->Developer->Developer Tools),
and open up the "network" tab, and try to do an upload, and look at the request, response, etc.

that may shed a lot of light.

I have used this plugin with javascript and java, but not with php.

also:  find a *really* simple example that uploads a file (with php, if you need to use that), and start building out from there.